# Is there better ways to intercept & modify network response in android?

Tags: android, frida, xposed

When testing a app(without source code), I need to mock some response from 3party apis that I don't has access to yet.

My current way to do this is LSPosed + ssl unpinning module + fiddler's autoresponder.

But I can't make it work without a computer, which making test the app outside the office very inconvenient.

I'm about to make a module to hook some apis to do so, maybe a frida script?
But before I do this...

ANY suggestions ? or is there a easier way to forgery responses for some certain links?

Comment: A simple workaround would be to install Termux + Mitmproxy (or mitmdump) on the device and develop a Mitmproxy script that provides the autoresponder functionality.

Comment: I look into Mitmproxy and find it's a great fit for my situation, but seems bit hard to make it run on a android phone, I'll have a try, thanks.

Comment: Within Termux running mitmproxy/mitmdump should be pretty simple. Just install Python via package manager and the use pip to download and install mitmproxy.